# Toast equivalent for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, toast

Is there any way using Xamarin Forms (not Android or iOS specific) to have a pop-up, like Android does with Toast, that needs no user interaction and goes away after a (short) period of time?

From searching around all I'm seeing are alerts that need user clicks to go away.

Answer (score 231):

There is a simple solution for this. By using the [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) you can easily get the Toast-Like approach in both Android and iOS.

**Create an interface in your common package.**

```
public interface IMessage
{
    void LongAlert(string message);
    void ShortAlert(string message);
}
```

**Android section**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MessageAndroid))]
namespace Your.Namespace
{
    public class MessageAndroid : IMessage
    {
        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    
        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS section**

In iOs there is no native solution like Toast, so we need to implement our own approach.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MessageIOS))]
namespace Your.Namespace
{
    public class MessageIOS : IMessage
    {
        const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
        const double SHORT_DELAY = 2.0;

        NSTimer alertDelay;
        UIAlertController alert;

        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
        }
        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
        }

        void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
        {
            alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
            {
                dismissMessage();
            });
            alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }

        void dismissMessage()
        {
            if (alert != null)
            {
                alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
            }
            if (alertDelay != null)
            {
                alertDelay.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that in each platform, we have to register our classes with DependencyService.

Now you can access out Toast service in anywhere in our project.

```
DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShortAlert(string message); 
DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert(string message);
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer to this question.  No third party plugins or libraries needed.

Comment: in DependencyService line I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Yeah this is the best answer so far , i like dependency service

Comment: Full of win. Would you happen to have a UWP version of this as well?

Comment: Did you try the code? If you toast the second message before first one dismiss, the UI will stuck. The second message will never disappear.

Comment: @MengTim I have tried this code and working well, but didn't check with simultaneous toasts. Will check and update here.

Comment: @MengTim I seem to have fixed the stuck UI by creating a new alert and timer every time. Both need to be passed to `DismissMessage`.

Comment: @Ian Warburton Do you have a code sample for this? Thanks so much. I still need this function.

Comment: @AlexChengalan-Could you tell me why interface needed here. However without interface also we can do it.

Comment: @Arvindraja Its because I followed something like this: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-dependency-injection/ and I think which is better for dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have only one issue with it: How could you NOT call the interface IToaster? :)

Comment: @JoachimLøvf What if somebody wants to show snack bar instead of toast?  ;)

Comment: Gives an exception `System.TypeLoadException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>` on IOS and doesn't show on Android.

Comment: in DependencyService line I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." ? Any solution i have instance

Comment: public IMessage Message => DependencyService.Get<IMessage>();

Comment: @Razzzz if this exception appears you are missing the assembly class above the namespace

Comment: @JoycedeLanna Don't forget to **register** the interface in `MainActivity.cs`. Add this line of code before `LoadApplication(new App())` `DependencyService.Register<IMessage, MessageAndroid>();`

Answer (score 23):

You can use [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) Package from nuget and code like below,

```
Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(Message, new TimeSpan(3));
```

Answer (score 19):

Here's a version of Alex Chengalan's iOS [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44126899/221683) that avoids the UI sticking when multiple messages are shown...

```
public class MessageIOS : IMessage
    {
        const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
        const double SHORT_DELAY = 0.75;

        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
        }

        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
        }

        void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
        {
            var alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

            var alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, obj =>
            {
                DismissMessage(alert, obj);
            });

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }

        void DismissMessage(UIAlertController alert, NSTimer alertDelay)
        {
            if (alert != null)
            {
                alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
            }

            if (alertDelay != null)
            {
                alertDelay.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not working. not sure if that is something to do with the latest Ios version but no longer working

Answer (score 17):

You can use `SnackBar` from [Xamarin Community toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit) package, which uses  native implementation in platforms where natively supported, because `Toast` is deprecated in API level 30, a `SnackBar` without an Action is equivalent to a Toast.

> This method was deprecated in API level 30.
> Custom toast views are deprecated. Apps can create a standard text toast with the makeText(android.content.Context, java.lang.CharSequence, int) method, or use a Snackbar when in the foreground. Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#R, apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R or higher that are in the background will not have custom toast views displayed. ([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast)).

### [Starting with Xamarin Community toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/get-started)

1. Install the Package on all your projects
2. include the namespace `using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Extensions;`
3. In your page code-behind show a SnackBar upon an event

```
await this.DisplayToastAsync("This is a Toast Message");
await this.DisplayToastAsync("This is a Toast Message for 5 seconds", 5000);
```

You may specify a duration for the SnackBar to disappear (in milliseconds) or leave the default one which equals 3 seconds.

[image]

---

### Resources

#### [SnackBar Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/SnackBarPage.xaml.cs)

**Official Repo** https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit

**Official Docs** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/

---

#### EDIT

1. **Anchored Toast:** You may anchor the toast above a view (like screenshot above) by simply calling the extension method `DisplayToastAsync()` from that view (anchor) object instead from the page instance (`this`):

```
<Button x:name="floatingButton" .../>

await floatingButton.DisplayToastAsync("This is a Toast Message for 5 seconds", 5000);
```

2. **Padding and corner radius:** (starting from xct version 1.3.0 preview-1)

You can set the corner radius and the padding for your Toast like the following example:

```
var messageOptions = new MessageOptions
{
    Message = "Toast with Padding and round corner",
    Foreground = Color.White,
    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(16),
    Padding = new Thickness(20)
};

var options = new ToastOptions
    {
        MessageOptions = messageOptions,
        CornerRadius = new Thickness(40, 40, 0, 0),
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#CC0000")
    };

await this.DisplayToastAsync(options);
```

[image]

[image]

PS: The same properties could be applied for the `SnackBar` view.

---

#### EDIT2

If what xct `SnackBar` offers doesn't fulfil your requirements or you want to display not only text but some complexe view, you might have to use a [popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup) instead.

Comment: How to display the text at the center and how to provide the margin to the snackbar

Comment: I wish I had seen this before trying the top voted answer.   Good lord.

Comment: @Priyanka not sure about that if you think it could be a new feature you can request it in GitHub repo, or check the Popup control (altought it might be an overkill in this case). Krausladen good to know it's helpful

Answer (score 11):

Adding to Alex's answer, here's the UWP variant:

```
public class Message : IMessage {
  private const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
  private const double SHORT_DELAY = 2.0;

  public void LongAlert(string message) =>
    ShowMessage(message, LONG_DELAY);

  public void ShortAlert(string message) =>
    ShowMessage(message, SHORT_DELAY);

  private void ShowMessage(string message, double duration) {
    var label = new TextBlock {
      Text = message,
      Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White),
      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    };
    var style = new Style { TargetType = typeof(FlyoutPresenter) };
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black)));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FrameworkElement.MaxHeightProperty, 1));
    var flyout = new Flyout {
      Content = label,
      Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Full,
      FlyoutPresenterStyle = style,
    };

    flyout.ShowAt(Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement);

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration) };
    timer.Tick += (sender, e) => {
      timer.Stop();
      flyout.Hide();
    };
    timer.Start();
  }
}
```

Coloring and styling is up to you, the `MaxHeight`is actually required to keep the height at the minimum.

Comment: So registering it as a Dependency Service does not need for the UWP?

Comment: It works exactly as the other two variants. Yes, a dependency service.

Answer (score 9):

We'd normally use Egors Toasts plugin, but as it requires permissions on iOS for a current project we've gone a different route using `Rg.Plugins.Popup` nuget (https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).

I wrote a basic xaml/cs page of type PopupPage,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<popup:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         x:Class="YourApp.Controls.ToastPage">
...
```

and had it created by a service, whose interface you registered at app start or use `Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService` to fetch the service would be viable too.

The service news up the PopupPage derived page, and does

```
await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(newToastPage);
await Task.Delay(2000);
await PopupNavigation.PopAllAsync();
```

The Popup page can be dismissed by the user by tapping outside the page display (assuming it hasn't filled the screen).

This seems to work fine on iOS/Droid, but I'm open to correction if anyone knows what this is a risky way of doing it.

Comment: rg popups are great. I do similar workaround for loading display or activity indicator on full page. problem with other plugins are they are dependent on async functions and main thread but rg popup can run on 2nd thread which makes it very useful. good idea indeed but I wish to have native look like on android toasts.

Comment: So far this is the best method to do cross platform toast. Rg.Popup is super flexibile, and i use it in almost every project. No need to use other plugins or platform code to display toasts,

Answer (score 6):

You can use IUserDialog [NuGet](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) and simply use it's toastAlert

```
var toastConfig = new ToastConfig("Toasting...");
toastConfig.SetDuration(3000);
toastConfig.SetBackgroundColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(12, 131, 193));

UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(toastConfig);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code snippet that I am using to show the toast in Xamarin.iOS

```
  public void ShowToast(String message, UIView view)
    {
        UIView residualView = view.ViewWithTag(1989);
        if (residualView != null)
            residualView.RemoveFromSuperview();

        var viewBack = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(83, 0, 300, 100));
        viewBack.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        viewBack.Tag = 1989;
        UILabel lblMsg = new UILabel(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 20, 300, 60));
        lblMsg.Lines = 2;
        lblMsg.Text = message;
        lblMsg.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        lblMsg.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        viewBack.Center = view.Center;
        viewBack.AddSubview(lblMsg);
        view.AddSubview(viewBack);
        roundtheCorner(viewBack);
        UIView.BeginAnimations("Toast");
        UIView.SetAnimationDuration(3.0f);
        viewBack.Alpha = 0.0f;
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

@MengTim, to fix the multiple toast issue in @alex-chengalan's solution, I simply wrapped everything within `ShowAlert()` with a check to see if `alert` and `alertDelay` are null, then within `DismissMessage`, nulled out `alert` and `alertDelay`.

```
void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
    {
        if(alert == null && alertDelay == null) {
            alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
            {
                DismissMessage();
            });
            alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }
    }

    void DismissMessage()
    {
        if (alert != null)
        {
            alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
            alert = null;
        }
        if (alertDelay != null)
        {
            alertDelay.Dispose();
            alertDelay = null;
        }
    }
```

That seemed to at least clear up the UI hang, if you are looking for a quick fix. I was trying to display the toast on navigation to a new page, and believe that the `PresentViewController` being set was essentially cancelling out my navigation. Sorry I did not comment within the thread, my reputation is too low :(

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend `Plugin.Toast` library from `nuget`. It works well.

```
CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastMessage("my toast message");
```

or from ACR.UserDialogs Nuget libriary

```
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading");
```

Comment: Is there a way to move it to the top?
Customize and show multiples?

Comment: no. this library supports only basic toast messages. you just can change bg and text color and the duration of message.

Answer (score 3):

This is my improved `ShowAlert` version of Ian Warburton's version to ensure that the toast is displayed even on popup page. 
Furthermore, the toast is dissmissed if the user click outside the toast.
I used `UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet` that look likes toast but it also work with `UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert`

```
    void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

        var alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, obj =>
        {
            DismissMessage(alert, obj);
        });

        var viewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        while (viewController.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            viewController = viewController.PresentedViewController;
        }
        viewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, () =>
        {
            UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(_ => DismissMessage(alert, null));
            alert.View.Superview?.Subviews[0].AddGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);
        });
    }
```

I hope this will help someone !

Comment: thats awesome and working. especially with the popup page solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in mechanism in Forms, but this nuget package supplies something similar

https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin

Note: These are not Android style toasts as requested in the question but UWP style toasts which are system wide notifications.

Comment: Android Toast means completely different thing - it's a popup message. This library is for system-wide notifications.

Comment: Should have read the comment before I installed the library just to notice then that these are not android style toasts.. Please make that clear in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used
https://github.com/ishrakland/Toast/
In
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Toast/

Example:

```
CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastMessage ("Loading", Plugin.Toast.Abstractions.ToastLength.Short);
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I customised a custom popup with Rg.Plugins.Popup NuGet
this is an example:

```
 <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:ScaleAnimation 
        PositionIn="Center"
        PositionOut="Center"
        ScaleIn="1.2"
        ScaleOut="0.8"
        DurationIn="600"
        DurationOut="600"
        EasingIn="Linear"
       EasingOut="Linear"/>
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>

<Frame CornerRadius="10"  
    HeightRequest="30"
       VerticalOptions="End"
       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
       HasShadow="False"
        Padding="0" Margin="40,50"
       OutlineColor="LightGray">
    <StackLayout 
    Opacity="0.4"
       BackgroundColor="White">
    <Label
        x:Name="lbl"
        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"

        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="12">
                <Label.FontFamily>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="NewJuneMedium" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Label.FontFamily>
            </Label>
</StackLayout>
    </Frame>
```

then in your basecontentpage you can add the following code, to show and hide the "toast" after a while:

```
public async void showpopup(string msg)
    {
        await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new Toast(msg));
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        await Navigation.PopPopupAsync(true);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The iOS answers above worked for me but for one little problem -- a warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

After some search, I came across this [unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45478503/1758350) which helped.  The poster commented "This looks stupid but works", which is right on both counts.

So, I modified the ShowAlert() function above with these lines, which seem to work:

```
    var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
    while ( rootVC.PresentedViewController != null) {
        rootVC = rootVC.PresentedViewController;
    }
    rootVC.PresentViewController( alert, true, null);
```

Comment: Dang -- I see an even better version of this below from @Pierre-Alexandre Flèche. How did I miss it before?

Answer (score 0):

For UWP

```
public void ShowMessageFast(string message)
    {
        ToastNotifier ToastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlNodeList toastNodeList = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        toastNodeList.Item(0).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Test"));
        toastNodeList.Item(1).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(message));
        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
        audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-winsoundevent:Notification.SMS");

        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        toast.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(4);
        ToastNotifier.Show(toast);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Install nuget **[Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)**.
It contains **Toasts** exactly what you are looking for.

```
ToastEvent toastEvent = new ToastEvent();
var toastConfig = new ToastConfig(toastEvent,"Toasting...","");
toastConfig.SetDuration(2000);

UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(toastConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently use xamarin essential in android:

```
//access mainthread
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
     Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Alex's code, for UWP variant, I found a great implementation here
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin/

Just come and leave a clap for him :)

```
[assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Toast_UWP))]  
namespace ToastMessage.UWP  
{  
    class Toast_UWP : Toast  
    {  
        public void Show(string message)  
        {  
            ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText01;  
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);  
  
            XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");  
            toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(message));  
              
            XmlNodeList toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");  
            ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.scale-240.png");  
            ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "logo");  
  
            IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");  
            ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "short");  
  
            var toastNavigationUriString = "#/MainPage.xaml?param1=12345";  
            var toastElement = ((XmlElement)toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast"));  
            toastElement.SetAttribute("launch", toastNavigationUriString);  
  
            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);  
  
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

By default, your messages will be queued and notified one after one, delayed based on the message duration. If you want to replace the existing message by the new one immediately just add more code like below

```
ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove("YOUR_TAG");

// Code to create Toast message, like the above method

toast.Tag = "YOUR_TAG";
```

If you want to add audio to your toast message, add this to your code

```
var audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Default");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Xamarin.Toolkit and follow this information provided by MS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup

In my application I could manage it by putting every code-thing between a viewmodel, the view and a method called DismissThisPopup(). So it is possible to controll it from outside of the current Mainpage.

To acomplish your request.
You could call await Task.Delay(5000); //as example 5sec
after you called your popup.Open();
so it might look like:

```
    ...
var vm = new MyPopUpViewModel()
vm.DisplayText = "this could be your text";
vm.DelayTimeForDismiss = 5000;
vm.IsLightDismissAllowed = false; //used that you can not close the popup by clicking around
await vm.OpenPopupAsync();
```

then in your vm OpenPopUpAsync()

```
...other properties and stuff
internal PopUpLoadingView popup = new PopUpLoadingView();//this is the view created with the informations from MS

public async Task OpenPopUp()
{
 popup.BindingContext = this;            
 Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ShowPopup(popup: popup);
 await Task.Delay(DelayTimeForDismiss);
 popup.DismissThisPopup();
}
```

and in your PopUpLoadingView, insert this method:

```
...other stuff
        public void DismissThisPopup()
        {
            Dismiss(this);
        }
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use `DisplayAlert("", "", "", "" );`

Comment: This doesn't at all react like a toast, it needs an action to continue.