# Unable to get RootViewController in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I created app, which Authenticate using Azure AD

In Android it is working fine, but in iOS, it need `RootViewController` for load the page. But `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow` is null. So I am not able to get `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController`

Bellow is the code:

```
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
    graphResourceUri, 
    ApplicationID, 
    new Uri(returnUri), 
    new PlatformParameters(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController)
);
```

Any other way from which I can get `RootViewController`

Comment: Can you show where in your application you are calling  await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync? Maybe you are calling it to early?

Comment: try this : UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().RootViewController;

Comment: @ColeXia Wouldn't change anything if it is called too early.

Comment: Yeah,if you call this "AcquireTokenAsync" function before the window generates , the return of rootViewcontroller will be null certainly.

Comment: Your KeyWindow is "null" unless your view did appear. So override "ViewDidAppear()" and you can access "KeyWindow" and of course its "RootViewController".

Answer (score 3):

This looks stupid but works.

```
        UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        UIViewController presentedVC = window.RootViewController;
        while (presentedVC.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            presentedVC = presentedVC.PresentedViewController;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code also, but it is not working.

I got the root cause of this issue. Issue was, when I am going to access the RootViewController then there should be at least one page Initialized, but it is not Initialized so I am unable to get RootViewController

so I gave daily to Initialized the page then I got the RootViewController

Answer (score 0):

Access `RootViewController` after your window is actually created. 
Do this after `base.FinishedLauching`, like this:

```csharp
var result = base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
var platformParameters = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
App.AuthenticationClient.PlatformParameters = new PlatformParameters(platformParameters);
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of window you have loaded getting the RootViewController can be problematic. This version has been the most stable one I've tried thus far and avoids tail recursive loops.

```
    public UIViewController GetRootController(){
        var root = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        while (true)
        {
            switch (root)
            {
                case UINavigationController navigationController:
                    root = navigationController.VisibleViewController;
                    continue;
                case UITabBarController uiTabBarController:
                    root = uiTabBarController.SelectedViewController;
                    continue;
            }

            if (root.PresentedViewController == null) return root;
            root = root.PresentedViewController; 
        }
    }
```